# Javascript OOP initialization and method call issue

Tags: javascript, oop, initialization

I have a javascript class `person`, I have made Obj of it, works fine. But I need to access the function from `person` class.

When I tried to access I get `..not a function error`.

Please help!

Important... I need to initialize the 'person' class, and call the method exactly same way of my code. How??  Help!

Here is my code:

```
 var person = {
   setBasic: function(data) {
     alert(data.name + ' ' + data.age);
   },
   this:getPerson = function() {
     alert('get me');
   },
   success: null
 };

 //lets instantiate.enter code here

 var perObj = new person.setBasic({ 'name': 'ikair', 'age': 33, });

 // works fine..

 //now I need to call a function of person class:

 perObj.getPerson();

 //not working :(... how to call function with prev code?
```

Comment: I think var person should be a function, not just an Object set.  Then you add those functions to its prototype.

Answer (score 1):

```
function person() {
   this.setBasic = function(data) {
     alert(data.name + ' ' + data.age);
   };
   this.getPerson = function() {
     alert('get me');
   };
}

var perObj = new person();
perObj.setBasic({ name: 'ikair', age: 33 });
perObj.getPerson();
```

**Update:**

```
var person = {
   setBasic: function(data) {
     alert(data.name + ' ' + data.age);

     this.getPerson = function() {
       alert('get me');
     };
   }
};

var perObj = new person.setBasic({ name: 'ikair', age: 33 });
perObj.getPersion();
```

Comment: thanks Igor...but as i said my requirement is to initiate Object exactly my code..

var perObj = new person.setBasic({ 'name': 'ikair', 'age': 33, }); then call  perObj.getPerson(); ///here i m getting error

Comment: With your code you are assigning to `perObj` an object that is an instance of `persion.setBasic` function. It does not have a method called `getPerson`.

Comment: then how to change my code (person function/class) ..so it will have a method getPerson, and i can call by 
 var perObj = new person.setBasic({ 'name': 'ikair', 'age': 33, });     perObj.getPerson();

Comment: You did not use the code that I provided. I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k3L3J/17/

Answer (score 1):

You need a class and to give its prototype functions:

```
/**
 * Person class
 * @param {String} name Name of person
 * @param {Number} age Age of person
 */
function person(name, age) {
   this.name = name || "";
   this.age = age || 0;
   this.success = null;
}
person.prototype = {
   /**
    * Set the parameters of this object
    * @param {type} data
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   setBasic: function(data) {
      this.name = data.name;
      this.age = data.age;

      alert(data.name + ' ' + data.age);
      // Do you mean to use this?
      alert(this.name + ' ' + this.age);
   },
   /**
    * Alert out fields
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   getPerson: function() {
      alert(this.name + ' ' + this.age);
      alert('get me');
   }
};

/**
 * Make a person and print him out
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function main() {
   var perObj = new person("bob", 33);
   perObj.setBasic({
      name: "akira",
      age: 100
   });
   perObj.getPerson();
}
```

Comment: thanks but i must call like:
var perObj = new personsetBasic({
      name: "akira",
      age: 100
   });
then perObj.getPerson();
how? :(

Comment: What do you mean?  The first line in `main()` gives you an object with the fields you pass in the constructor.  You can stop after the first line.  I just put in the second line to show you that you can still use a function to set an initialized `person`'s values.  The `perObj.getPerson()` shows an alert that prints the `person`s `name` and `age`.

Comment: Sorry ..but i may not able describe my problem.
1. I need to initialize a js class like this:
   var perObj = new person.setBasic({ 'name': 'ikair', 'age': 33, });
   //person is class,
 2. then i call method like this:
    perObj.getPerson();
// getPerson is a function.

how?

Comment: `person` is not a class, it is an `Object` instance

Comment: @Ikhtiar I really am not sure how else to answer your question.  You instantiate `Objects` from faux `"Class"`es that are declared through `function` and then have more `function`s tacked onto their `prototype`.  To do the instantiating, you call `new [whatever function describes the class]()`  Maybe read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript It will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var person = {
   setBasic: function(data) {
   alert(data.name + ' ' + data.age);
   },
   getPerson: function() {
    alert('get me');
   },
   success: null
   };
   person.setBasic({ 'name': 'ikair', 'age': 33, });
   person.getPerson();
```

Comment: Note: the value of `this` starts to get muddled in this setup

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are all valid, but you could also restructure your code to be much simpler like this:

```
function Person(data){
    this.age = data.age;
    this.name = data.name;
};

Person.prototype.getData = function(){
    alert(this.name + " " + this.age);
};

var john = new Person({name: "John", age: 43});
john.getData();
```

And a JSFiddle to prove that it works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QLTry/)

Comment: thanks ..but must call like
var perObj = new personsetBasic({ name: "akira", age: 100 }); then perObj.getPerson(); how? :(

Comment: The way you want for format your code doesn't make any sense. And even if I were to try, I don't think I could get that code to run at all.